# how many runtimes can be created on a single worklight server

Tags: performance, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

Has there been any benchmarking done on how many runtimes can be created /supported on a single worklight/mobilefirst server instance? What we are trying to determine is how best can we setup a multi-tenant system such that each set of consumers has different applications being served off the same infrastructure/servers?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention the version of Worklight/MobileFirst that you are using, so the only thing I can think of is pointing you to the Scalability and Hardware Sizing documents available in the following location: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/additional-documentation/

Comment: Thanks Idan. We are using version 7.1

Comment: Please see the document for 7.1 and update your question if it does not answer it.